# É seguro usar as variáveis $_SERVER para logar erros?

Tags: php

Todos sabemos que é possível manipular algumas informações durante uma request, eu nunca tive de usar nada como `$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`, `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]` ou `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` pois eu sei que tem implicações na segurança.

Porém eu quero logar alguns erros no meu sistema, e pensei em usar essas variáveis para acrescentar detalhes em meu log caso uma URL não possa ser validada corretamente, ou seja, caso contenha caracteres que não se encaixem no `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.

Segue uma explicação de como a lógica funciona.

```
if (!filter_var( $url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{    
    $detalhes = array (
        'HTTP_HOST' => "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]",
        'REQUEST_URI' => "$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]",
        'REMOTE_ADDR' => "$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]"
        'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR' => "$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']"
    );

    $erro->gerar('20x0010', $detalhes);
}
```

Essa string `20x0010` é o código de erro interno que usamos na documentação para descrever erros do sistema, cada *[prefixo]x[sufixo]* representa um erro em determinada parte do sistema e a descrição, respectivamente.

Nessa função de `gerar()`, o sistema iria verificar o objeto `config` e determinar se o debug está ativo.

Caso o debug esteja ativo, será exibida uma tela para o desenvolvedor com todas as informações de saída, descrição do código do erro e descrições adicionais, que são as variáveis `$_SERVER`, caso contrário o usuário seria redirecionado à index. Em ambos os casos os erros são logados em um arquivo.

Achei que fosse importante logar essas informações pois os ataques mais básicos poderiam ser logados. Porém eu não sei se seria seguro utilizar essas variáveis para acrescentar mais detalhes ao log de erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $HTTP_SERVER_VARS contains the same initial information, but is not a superglobal. (Note that $HTTP_SERVER_VARS and $_SERVER are different variables and that PHP handles them as such). Also note that long arrays were removed since PHP 5.4.0 so $HTTP_SERVER_VARS doesn't exist anymore.

Significa que contêm apenas informação dos headers, caminhos e localização dos scripts, mas não são variáveis globais. Os valores dessa array são fornecidos pelo próprio servidor, sendo que nalguns servidores essa informação pode ser omitida. Se for para traçar linhas de erro, creio não haver problema, mas lembrando que o objectivo dos logs é registrar erros com mais detalhes possíveis, sem que o utilizador final tenha conhecimento destes detalhes, apenas o proprietário deve ser capaz de ler estas informações, porque na maior parte das vezes contêm informações relevantes para a segurança do site. Lê isto [aqui](http://php.net/manual/it/reserved.variables.server.php) se ainda estiveres nas bordas.

Comment: Sim, no caso as mensagens só são exibidas para o usuário caso o debug esteja ativo, o que não acontece em produção, somente na parte de desenvolvimento.  Vou ler o link que me passou, obrigado pela informação.

Answer (score 1):

A resposta à sua pergunta pode ser encontrada no próprio manual do PHP especificamente em: [$_SERVER](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)

destaco o paragrafo:

> $_SERVER é um array contendo informação como cabeçalhos, paths, e
>   localizações do script. As entradas neste array são criadas pelo
>   servidor web. Não há garantia que cada servidor web proverá algum
>   destes; servidores podem omitir alguns, ou fornecer outros não
>   listados aqui. Dito isso, um grande número dessas variáveis são
>   previstas pela » CGI 1.1 specification, então você deve estar hábil
>   para esperá-las.

Dito isto dizer que normalmente é seguro aceder a este `array`, no entanto e profissionalmente, se desejar uma solução sempre funcional independente da implementação do servidor quaisquer das suas variáveis podem ser replicadas.

Por exemplo o `HTTP_HOST` é normalmente parte do HTTP request. Se `HTTP_HOST` não estiver definido, o cliente pode ser uma de duas coisas: muito antigo (*HTTP 1.0 não suporta o HTTP_HOST*) ou foi um request realizado *directo* ao IP do web site.

Muitas das variáveis precedidas por "*HTTP_*" referem-se a variáveis presentes no cabeçalho do `request` e neste caso existem funções para a obtenção deste conteúdos.